# Javascript Substring replace with JQuerys contains selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a specific row in a column of an HTML table and replace an occurrence of a specific string with a given value.

I tried to use JQuery's `.html` but it just replaces everything in the row with the given value. A `.text().replace()` returned me false.

Here's my code:

```
function ReplaceCellContent(find, replace)
    {      
        //$(".export tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + find + "')").html(function (index, oldHtml) {
        //    return oldHtml.replace(find, replace);
        //});

        $(".export tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + find + "')").text($(this).text().replace(find, replace));

        //$(".export tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + find + "')").html(replace);
    }



$('.export tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function () {
                        var field = $(this).text();
                        var splitter = field.split(':');

                        if (splitter[2] === undefined) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            var splitter2 = splitter[2].split(',');
                        }

                        if (splitter2[0] === undefined) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            $.post(appPath + 'api/list/', {action: 'getPW', pw: splitter2[0]})
                                .done(function (result) {
                                    ReplaceCellContent(splitter2[0], result);
                                });


                        }
                    });
```

I'm iterating through every row of the column 4 and extracting the right string. This is going through an AJAX post call to my function which returns the new string which I want to replace it with.

```
splitter2[0] // old value
result // new value
```

I hope someone could help me. I'm not that deep into JS/JQuery.

Comment: I'm starting to think I have a big recursion mess in there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findSmith findJill findJohn

```
 var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("classes");
    var replaceCellContent = (find, replace) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            if (classes[i].innerText.includes(find)) {
                classes[i].innerText = classes[i].innerText.replace(find, replace);
            }
        }
    }
```

this replaces all "fill" occurrences to "look".
I love to use vanilla JS, I'm not really a fan of JQuery but this surely should work on your code.

Comment: I used your solution and restructured my code and threw a lot of it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say give all your table rows a class name of  "trClasses"

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("trClasses");
for (var I = 0; I < rows.length; I++) {
     rows.innerText.replace("yourText");
}
```

The innerText property would return the text in your HTML tag.

I'm a newbie too, but this should work. Happy Coding!

Comment: I already have the iteration through my rows with JQuerys .each so. And I don't want to replace all text just a substring. But thanks!

Comment: is the string a phrase or just a word?

Comment: It's just a word. But I'd be happy if it fits my code constellation above.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
var tds = $("td"); 
  for( var i = 0; i < tds.length ; i++){ 
   if ( $(tds[i]).text().includes("abc") ){ 
      var replacetext = $(tds[i]).text().replace("abc", "test");
      $(tds[i]).text(replacetext);
   } 
 }
```